# Applying Function Using // with additional arguments

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, notation

I was trying to apply functions at the end of an expression, for example:

```
expr //Simplify
```

But sometimes I need additional arguments for `Simplify[]` such as:

```
Simplify[expr, TimeConstraint->5]
```

Is there a way to do this using the `//` notation?

Comment: try `expr // Simplify[#, TimeConstraint->5]&`

Comment: @Jason B. Yes.. somehow it didn't appear on my search. Also thanks, kglr.